# Google Script - Issue Setting the VAxis Min and Max

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, linechart

I am currently building a line chart and trying to set the *min* and *max* `vAxis` properties by using the code:

```
var currChart = currSheet.newChart().addRange(currRange);
currChart.setPosition(row, col, 5, 5);
var builtChart = currChart.asLineChart()
                        .setTitle(title)
                        .setYAxisTitle(axisLabel)
                        .setOption('useFirstColumnAsDomain','true')
                        .setOption('interpolateNulls', 'true')
                        .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', min)
                        .setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', max)
                        .setOption('vAxis.gridlines.count', 7)
                        .setOption('hAxis.gridlines.count', 9)
                        .setOption('chartArea.left', 80)
                        .setOption('chartArea.top', 70)
                        .setOption('chartArea.width', 360)
                        .setOption('chartArea.height', 250)
                        .build();
```

*Min* and *max* are passed into this method as integers. They are put into `.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', min)` and `.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', max)`

When the sheet is made, say for example i pass in **1** as my min and **15** as my max for the vAxis. The sheet generated will ignore the options and create a sheet like this:

[image]

Why are my options being ignored? What can I do set the vAxis min and max?

Comment: Im comparing what i typed to what is in the google API and its the same. What could cause this setOption not to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This problem was solved by replacing `.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.min', min)` and `.setOption('vAxis.viewWindow.max', max)`

with

`.setOption('vAxes', {0: {title: '', textStyle: {fontSize: 10}, titleTextStyle: {fontSize : 8}, viewWindow: {min: minNum, max:maxNum}}})`